# Lambda expressions, concurrency and static variables

Tags: multithreading, c++11, lambda, concurrency

As far as I know, such use of static  storage within lambda is legal. Essentially it counts number of entries into the closure:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>


typedef std::pair<int,int> mypair;

std::ostream &operator<< (std::ostream &os, mypair const &data) {
    return os << "(" << data.first << ": " << data.second << ") ";
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    std::vector<mypair> v;
    std::cin >> n;
    v.reserve(n);

    std::for_each(std::begin(v), std::end(v), [](mypair& x) {
        static int i = 0;
        std::cin >> x.second;
        x.first = i++;
    });

    std::for_each(std::begin(v), std::end(v), [](mypair& x) {
        std::cout << x;
    });

    return 0;
}
```

Let assume I have a container 'workers' of threads.

```
std::vector<std::thread> workers;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    workers.push_back(std::thread([]() 
    {
        std::cout << "thread #" << "start\n";
        doLengthyOperation();
        std::cout << "thread #" << "finish\n";
    }));
}
```

Code in doLengthyOperation() is contained and self-sufficient operation, akin a new process creation.

Provided I join them using for_each and the stored variable in question must count number of *active* tasks, not just number of entries, what possible implementations for such counter are there, if I want to avoid to rely onto global variables to avoid someone else messing up with it and allowing automatic support for separate "flavors" of threads.

```
std::for_each(workers.begin(), workers.end(), [](std::thread &t) 
    {
        t.join();
    });
```

Surrounding scope would die  quickly after finishing thread starts, may repeat , adding new threads to the container is possible, and that must be global variable, which I want to avoid. More of, the whole  operation is a template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to handle this is to capture an instance of `std::atomic<int>` which provides a thread safe counter. Depending on the lifetime of lambdas and the surrounding scope, you may wish to capture by reference or shared pointer.

To take your example:

```
std::vector<std::thread> workers;
auto counter = std::make_shared<std::atomic<int>>(0);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    workers.push_back(std::thread([counter]() 
    {
        std::cout << "thread #" << "start\n";
        (*counter)++;
        doLengthyOperation();

        (*counter)--;
        std::cout << "thread #" << "finish\n";
    }));
}
```

Comment: surrounding scope would die  quickly after finishing thread starts, may repeat , adding new threads to the container, and that must be global variable, which I want to   avid. More of, the whole  operation is a template. Does that provide counter after the  scope dies?

Comment: @Swift The counter must have the same scope as the workers container, if that needs to be global the counter will need to be as well. If you have more detail about the workers container I might be able to add more detail.

Comment: aha, got it. so I possibly still need to create a template class that would   house the container for each flavor  and a counter for them. What actually prevents me from declaring counter within lambda as a static?

Comment: If you use static it prevents you from using the counter in any other lambdas, and you would need to use an atomic counter anyway. Also it is really unclear as to which lambda instances the static applies to if you are putting this in a template. It seems to follow the rules of a function within an inner class but its not clear.

Comment: well, it should be unique for that lambda, which is unique to template instance. Yeah, it is unclear, I wasn't even sure if the original example, with no concurrency, is working, but apparently it does.